# How can I login and download a file with Perl's WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, mechanize, login-script

I'm trying to use Perl's WWW::Mechanize to download a file. I have to login the website before and then, after having validated the form, download the file.

The thing is, after hours, I didn't succeed doing what I want. At the end, the script save a file which is not a zip file but a html file with nothing interesting in it.

Here is the script I've done :

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Crypt::SSLeay;

my $login = "MyMail";
my $password = "MyLogin";
my $url = 'http://www.lemonde.fr/journalelectronique/donnees/protege/20101002/Le_Monde_20101002.zip';

$bot = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$bot->cookie_jar(
    HTTP::Cookies->new(
        file           => "cookies.txt",
        autosave       => 1,
        ignore_discard => 1,
    )
);

$response = $bot->get($url);

$bot->form_name("formulaire");
$bot->field('login', $login);
$bot->field('password', $password);
$bot->submit();

$response = $bot->get($url);
my $filename = $response->filename;

if (! open ( FOUT, ">$filename" ) ) {
    die("Could not create file: $!" );
}
print( FOUT $bot->response->content() );
close( FOUT );
```

Could you help me finding what mistakes I've done?

Comment: Have you tried using curl to download the file on the command line? They might be checking the user-agent; so make sure that you change it to imitate a browser. Something like ` curl --user-agent "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"`

Answer (score 3):

There are some hidden input fields which I assume are filled in when you navigate to the download using a browser rather than using a URL directly.

In addition, they are setting some cookies via JavaScript and those would not be picked up by Mechanize. However, there is a plugin [WWW::Mechanize::Plugin::JavaScript](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aJavaScript) which might be able to help you with that (I have no experience with it).

Use [LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) to see what gets submitted by the browser and replicate that (assuming you are not violating their TOS).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'll try to find out what's going on with these fiels.

Comment: I'm not violating anything since I'm a registered user to this website ! :)

Comment: @user467954 Well, their TOS might still prohibit using bots to access content. I am not implying you are doing anything wrong. You just never know with newspapers these days.

Answer (score -4):

The problem you mention is well known in Mechanize. The simplest solution is to use the Raspo library.

Comment: rooh, on a vu pire comme anglais tout de même !

Comment: @perlman The poster posted in English. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/130608

Comment: Posting in French would be acceptable, if the english translation were also included for the benefit of everyone else who wishes to learn from this problem.

Comment: If it's the choice between a french answer and no answer, I'll take the french answer. The wikiwonders of Stackoverflow allow you to edit the answers to provide the translation. It took me longer to type this comment than it did to translate the post for everyone. Unfortunately, the answer is still useless.

Comment: The English was fine and the question perfectly understandable. And indeed the French answer was useless.